# why won't Ruby OptionParser read all of my arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split, optionparser

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# OptionParser
require 'optparse'

options = {}
optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|
    opts.banner = '...'

    # This option inputs ...
    options[:Lap1] = []
    opts.on('-1', '--Lap1 filepath1,width1,height1,a1,first1,last1', String, '...') do|l1|
        options[:Lap1] = l1.split(',')  
    end
end
optparse.parse!
```

My goal is to have an array of the separate inputs separated by commas. However this code only outputs the first variable `$filepath1`.

The output of:

```
puts(options[:Lap1])
```

and

```
puts(options[:Lap1][0]
```

is just the the first variable `filepath1`.

```
puts(options[:Lap1][1])
```

is `nil`, when it should be the variable `width1`.

Any suggestions or potential fixes would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the parse! method on your OptionParser object after declaring all the options.

```
optparse.parse!
```

Comment: I have that, I forgot to add it on the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write that code a bit differently:

```
require 'optparse'
require 'pp'

options = {
  :Lap1 => []
}

optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = '...'

  # This option inputs ...
  opts.on(
    '-1', '--Lap1 filepath1,width1,height1,a1,first1,last1',
    Array,
    '...'
  ) { |l1| options[:Lap1] = l1 }
end.parse!
pp options
```

Running that at the command-line:

```
ruby test.rb -1 filepath1,width1,height1,a1,first1,last1
```

Results in:

```
{:Lap1=>["filepath1", "width1", "height1", "a1", "first1", "last1"]}
```

Testing using `--Lap1` results in:

```
ruby test.rb --Lap1 filepath1,width1,height1,a1,first1,last1
```

And:

```
{:Lap1=>["filepath1", "width1", "height1", "a1", "first1", "last1"]}
```

In my opinion, you should set your defaults when you define your `options` hash.

```
options = {
  :Lap1 => []
}
```

Also, notice the use of `Array` instead of `String`. OptionParser will automatically split a comma-delimited string into an array of individual elements if you use `Array`, saving you that `split` step, and avoiding a bit of confusing code. See the documentation for OptionParser's [`make_switch`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-make_switch) method for more information.

Comment: So, I still get the same error even when doing it that way. It only seems to read the first variable.

Comment: Well, I don't know how you're calling the code from the command-line because you didn't say. The command-lines above work correctly with the code I gave.

Comment: I ran it exactly like that. It was working a couple days ago, but now I keep running into this problem.

Comment: Then you have something that changed on your system. The command-line given is valid and correct. Confirm your Ruby version is correct.